# How to Compare 2 DataFrames which have different Column Names(have same and different values) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

I have several dataframes, each has different and same column names, and the columns with same and different column names may have same values. I want to find the columns in one dataset which has matching values with other dataset' columns(may have same or different column names). Is there any efficient way to do that using python?

For example:

```
df1:   ID count Name
       0   1    A  
       1   2    B  
       2   3    C  


df2:   person_id count_number Name Value
        0           1          A    11
        2           3          C    22
        3           4          D    33

df3:   key  Value
       11    11
       22    22
       33    33
```

I tried 'isin()':this is not efficient, and 'datacompy': can't be used? because I have different column names.

My expected output: the column names that have matchings. And also better show how many matchings do they have.

For example: In this example, I want to find the matching columns of df1, df2 and df3. And the output I want is: Their pairwise matches: For df1 and df2: ID&person_id; count&count_number, Name; for df2 and df3: Value, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to make a [mcve], including your expected output from the given input, and _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research, so that we understand how to help

Answer (score 0):

As you have no expected output, it's hard to answer. A first proposition:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, left_on='ID', right_on='person_id').merge(df3, on='Value')

   ID  count Name_x  person_id  count_number Name_y  Value  key
0   0      1      A          0             1      A     11   11
1   2      3      C          2             3      C     22   22
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, thank you for the reply! I've updated my expected output in the post, I don't want to merge these df, I want the columns that having matchings. Thanks!

Comment: Can you build manually your output dataframe for your sample to understand how the output should be, please?